# Can I play Halo 4 On Xbox One as a Disc?

Tags: halo-4

I gave my Halo 4 disc to a friend who has a Xbox 360. I was going to pick later to play it on my Xbox One but, I don't know if I would be even able to play it or not on my Xbox.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, inserting the disk into the system will play the game like it were on the 360. It may have to download/install updates, but it is 100% backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/games-apps/backward-compatibility/play-xbox-360-games-on-xbox-one),

> Select digital and disc-based Xbox 360 and original Xbox games can be
> played on Xbox One. These backward-compatible games use an emulator
> for the older Xbox operating systems, providing most features of those
> systems, such as broadcasting and screenshot and game-clip captures.

**This means most games should be able to be played on it.** [Here](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/games/backward-compatibility) is a list of the supported games.